# Yocto autotools not configuring and compiling

Tags: raspberry-pi, cross-compiling, autotools, bitbake

I am new to yocto and trying to build a package for raspberry pi.
I am using the BSP layer from https://github.com/djwillis/meta-raspberrypi.

Am able to build the image using BSP without any problem. But when I
added a new layer to add packages, am getting error.

I tried testing with the hello world auto tooled package. This hello
world is the hello world autotooled package downloaded from
ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.gz.  When trying
to execute that bb, am getting the error as follows,

```
| make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
```

My bb file is as follows,

```
DESCRIPTION = "Dummy"

SECTION = "package"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://hello/"

inherit autotools gettext
```

After executing this bb file, i took a look at the logs of configure.
It says nothing to configure.

Please help me with what's wrong with this process I am following?

Answer (score 2):

Your error

```
    make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Means the bitbake recipe does not a rule for "install" defined. What you need in your recipe is something as follows

```
    do_install () {
        #either leave this empty or put instructions for installation 
    }
```

You also need a SRC_URI for hello.c system.h and the make file included with that hello world package.

Have a look at this tutorial http://stevephillips.me/blog/adding-custom-software-to-bitbake-oe-core which has a full bitbake recipe example

Comment: I have downloaded hello world tar from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.xz and extracted to "hello" directory. All c,h and necessary config files are present inside. When i looked at the logs of do_configure(), it says Nothing to Configure.

Comment: Have you tried defining the do_configure as empty? try putting "do_configure () {}" at the bottom of your bitbake recipe

Comment: That is not at all what the error means.  yocto is invoking "make install" but the makefile its using does not contain an "install" target.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because OE cannot find the source. Try changing the SRC_URI to the address of the hello world tar file. OE then implicitly knows the location of the source.

```
DESCRIPTION = "Dummy"

SECTION = "package"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/hello/hello-2.7.tar.gz"

inherit autotools
```

Looking at what you did (which is not conventional) you can also try setting the source directory "S" to "${WORKDIR}/hello"

```
DESCRIPTION = "Dummy"

SECTION = "package"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PR = "r0"

SRC_URI = "file://hello/"

inherit autotools

S = ${WORKDIR}/hello
```